PC won't post, keeps rebooting despite having replaced all major components
I think I’ve tried everything to get my trusty computer back up and running, and could really use some help from people more knowledgeable than myself.
My computer suddenly wouldn’t post with no previous warning, so I set about to fix it, while getting some new components in at the same time.
Nothing I’ve tried works - the computer starts, the MB, GPU and LED lights come on, the fans spin, but only for around 40 seconds - then it reboots, and the same thing happens.
I’ve replaced the motherboard (first on the suspect list), replaced the PSU (upgraded to a 750W from a 650W), I’ve replaced the CPU (upgraded my Ryzen 7 1800X to a 3700X), I’ve replaced my RTX 3700 with an RTX Titan), I’ve shuffled around the RAM, I reseated all connectors, I’ve cleared the CMOS (both shortening the PINs and removing the battery) - no change whatsoever.
After weeks of struggling with this, I’m all out of ideas, and would be extremely grateful for any help from you guys.
Maybe I’m just missing something stupid, after having put everything together again with the new parts (CPU and GPU - I went back to my original motherboard after replacing it made no change).
This is my setup (photo attached)
Motherboard: ASRock X370 Killer SLI (tried switching out with a ASRock X570 Taichi Premium, switched back after no change - exact same behavior))
PSU: Corsair CX750
CPU: Ryzen 7 3700X
GPU: Nvidia RTX Titan
AM: 4 x 16GB DD-4 (2 x ipjaws GSkill + 2 x XPG AData)
CPU Cooler: CyberPower PC-branded liquid cooler (looks simila to a Corsair H60)
Case: Phantek5


You downgraded from an RTX 3070 to an RTX Titan? Did you upgrade the firmware on the motherboard before you went to the newer generation processor? Your two screenshots are identical.

if you have more-or-less replaced the PC, have you tried a different power outlet? I've seen issues with power from the walll cause people to replace machines repeatedly without avail.

RAM, Case, CPU Cooler are the only constants?

Yes, I switched out the 3070 to the Titan (not exactly a downrgade considering that I use a lot of VRAM usually).
The photo uploads glitched on me, hence the identical photos.

Yep, the cooler, the RAM and the case are the only constraints I can think of. Power cable going into the wall is another, but that's it.

I do have the stock cooler that came with the 3700, I could use that instead of the water cooler, bit I figured it'd be more noisy.

@Ramhound  I wasn't able to update the firmware as the machine doesn't boot. I also tried an RTX 1066 that I've used before - no change.

The system does not even seem to be turned on. I see absolutely no lights on the motherboard. Did you verify your processors are compatible with your new motherboard at the earliest firmware revision?

Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? and/or I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them? for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Strip out everything non-essential, try one stick of ram, one drive, use the onboard graphics instead of the GPU, unplug the water cooking (short period to get past 40 seconds). If that fails swap to a second stick of ram, plug in a different drive. Also plug it in a different room in the house to rule out interferance.

@AndyGee - start with no drive, any system should POST without one

Thanks everyone for trying to help!
In a fit of frustration, I retried booting from my old 1800X CPU again after having cleared CMOS (I have tried this umpteenth times) - and lo and behold, the system booted right away! (No idea why - Moon phase?)
My question now is a bit simpler - I now need to flash the BIOS so I can run my new 3700X CPU, and want to do this correctly.
I seem to recall that this is a two step process using my 1800X while flashing, then switching to the 3700X and doing it again to get the latest BIOS, but the ASRock website isn't exactly crystal clear about this...

@JaromandaX Wow, I've had the incorrect belief you needed some storage for POST for 30+ years! Thanks for fixing that for me :)

@Yggdrasilbury - the X570 Taichi supports the 3700X in ALL versions of BIOS - so, the fact that the 3700X failed seems worrying. As for what to do on the X370 Mobo - it depends on what BIOS version you have now - seems you need to update to P3.50 if currently below that, then P5.10, then P5.40 - at this point the 3700X should be supported - Note: P5.40 is the only BIOS version that both the 1800X and 3700X are supported (officially)
